# How can I troubleshoot Sharepoint workflows?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm a bit lost here and I can't find much documentation.

Comment: Are you talking about workflows defined in SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

.NET workflows or ones created using SharePoint designer?

I've only got latter experience and they aren't really easy to debug, you really just have to do them 1 step at a time and test up to each step.

You can view the workflow state as well in SharePoint when you go to the List Settings (sorry I don't have a WSS machine to look at currently).

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Slace.  Make sure you create your workflows in SP Designer to be executable from the browser, even if eventually they'll only be kicked off by status changes.  That will in itself make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: What do you mean under "executable from the browser"?

Comment: Heh, i's been a while since I've done any SP development, so my recollection may be fuzzy, and things may be different in SP2012, or whatever the current version is, but when you develop a workflow in SPDesigner in the last version I worked with you could choose whether or not a workflow could be triggered from the browser and executed. If you didn't design them that way the only way to trigger it was to actually change a record in such a way that triggered the workflow, which makes troubleshooting a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about SharePoint Designer workflows? You can convert them into .NET workflows following [these steps](http://sergeluca.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E8A06D5F2F585013!1256.entry). 
From there, you can debug them. I haven't tried it myself (yet).

Answer (score 0):

As stated, your only real choice for debugging SharePoint Designer workflows is by either going through the painful process of converting them into .NET worklows, or doing things like writing out the History List after every single step so you can see what is failing.

However, even .NET workflows are very difficult to debug in VS2005.  In VS2008, they added the ability to more easily debug workflows developed using that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've already seen this :-)
[Troubleshoot workflow errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298927.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/07/25/debugging-tips-for-sharepoint-and-wss-exceptions.aspx) has some great debugging tips for SharePoint.  It gives a good general approach to development/debugging.  Here are a few of the tools that are referenced:

- [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) (in fact all of the SysInternals tools)
- [IE Dev Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)
- [XsltMajic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331026)
- [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/installx86.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned the obvious resource for SharePoint Debugging -- the ULS logs.  A ULS viewer filtered on a level of "unexpected" will usually show you the logged cause for the failure.